# ios show alert bar at bottom that scrolls up on click or drag

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, alert

I am trying to implement an alert/notification bar that will appear at the bottom of the page, and when clicked will scroll up and cover the entire screen (just like Kayak or PageOnce apps show it). Here's how it looks right now (Have uploaded the images at below URLs):

Image showing alerts bar at the bottom
http://www.anony.ws/hLe

Alerts bar opened up
http://www.anony.ws/hLl

It works but not completely. One thing, the alert view is not able to cover the navigation bar (alert frame's origin y is 0 in the attached screenshot for opened up view). If I make the frame's y negative to go further up, the view goes behind the navigation bar. How can I make it work so that the alerts view covers the entire screen (including the navigation bar).

Here's what I have done:

1. In the "Member Center" view controller, on viewDidLoad, I am creating a new view (my AlertView), changing it's frame to show up at the bottom and then adding it as a subview to current view:

   ```
   CGFloat alertBarHeight = 25;
   CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
   frame.origin.y = frame.size.height - alertBarHeight;
   AlertsView *av = [[AlertsView alloc] initWithFrame:frame withController:self height:alertBarHeight]; // Its a custom init method that just stores a reference to the invoking controller
   [self.view addSubview:av];
   ```
2. My show/hide code is in AlertsView.m and looks like this:

   ```
   - (void) showOrHideAlerts:(id)sender
   {
   if (self.isOpen)
   {
       // Close the alerts view
       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
       animations:^{
           CGRect frame = self.frame;
           frame.origin.y = self.invokingController.view.frame.size.height - self.barHeight;
           self.frame = frame;
       }
       completion:^(BOOL finished)
       {
            self.isOpen = NO;
       }];
   }
   else
   {
       // Show the alerts view
       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
       animations:^{
           CGRect frame = self.frame;
           frame.origin.y = 0;// - [self.invokingController.navigationController navigationBar].frame.size.height;
           //frame.origin.y = 20;
           self.frame = frame;
       }
       completion:^(BOOL finished)
       {
            self.isOpen = YES;
       }];

   }
   }
   ```

I feel that I am not implementing it correctly. Please guide me on what's the best way to implement such a feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your alert view to navigation controller view as below and not in the current view:

```
AlertsView *av = [[AlertsView alloc] initWithFrame:frame withController:self height:alertBarHeight]; // Its a custom init method that just stores a reference to the invoking controller

[self.navigationController.view addSubview:av];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That helps. The view now shows up on top of the nav bar. I did try that earlier too but reverted because I got into another problem. See if you can help me with that too. As you might see in the screenshot, the alerts is a Table View. Clicking on that will go to an Alert Details screen. Now, I am not using TableViewController here, just TableView, as a child of AlertsView. What I want to do it, when someone clicks on an Alert, it takes the user to the alert details screen, within its own navigation hierarchy, with a left nav button to go back to all alerts screen.

Comment: @AC1 You still in the current view in navigation stack no? You just added a view as subView of current view. Navigation not working in this case??

Comment: Its working but not the way I expect it to. So my navigation stack looks like this: Home -> Another Screen. Another Screen is showing the alert bar (AlertView) at the bottom, which is added as a subview to the nav controller and not the current page's (Another Screen's) subview. So, when I click on an alert after opening the AlertView, I added the alert details controller to the nav stack, that's get displayed but is hidden behind the AlertView. Also the back button on the alert details page should take me to AlertsView opened up, like how I left it when I clicked on an Alert from the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can Hide The navigation bar when alert view is Open And Again Show it when Alert View is Closed .

to hide :

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

to Show:

```
self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It doesn't work the way it should. As soon as I hide the nav bar, the whole view is shifted up to accommodate the extra space available, so it gives kind of a jerky look, where the background view is also moving up along with the Alerts view.